# storing html code in mysql and render it using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing some html codes in mysql database. but when I get the codes in my PHP file, I get the html file echo-ed on my page!

example html code:

```
&lt;span style="background-color: #eeeeee;"&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00ISQWBEG/ref=as_li_tf_il?ie=UTF8&amp;camp=1634&amp;creative=6738&amp;creativeASIN=B00ISQWBEG&amp;linkCode=as2&amp;tag=wwwtrafficelb-21"&gt;&lt;img border="0" src="http://ws-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B00ISQWBEG&amp;Format=_SL250_&amp;ID=AsinImage&amp;MarketPlace=GB&amp;ServiceVersion=20070822&amp;WS=1&amp;tag=wwwtrafficelb-21" &gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;img src="http://ir-uk.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=wwwtrafficelb-21&amp;l=as2&amp;o=2&amp;a=B00ISQWBEG" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" /&gt;<br>
```

and this is how it gets displayed on my php page:

```
<span style="background-color: #eeeeee;"><a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00ISQWBEG/ref=as_li_tf_il?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=6738&creativeASIN=B00ISQWBEG&linkCode=as2&tag=wwwtrafficelb-21"><img border="0" src="http://ws-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B00ISQWBEG&Format=_SL250_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=GB&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=wwwtrafficelb-21" ></a><img src="http://ir-uk.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=wwwtrafficelb-21&l=as2&o=2&a=B00ISQWBEG" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
```

I did try this:

```
$body2 = strip_tags($body);
echo $body2;
```

but that didn't work!

could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Looks like you've stored the HTML in your database in its escaped form. You should probably convert all that data to be pure HTML without escaping. `strip_tags` just removes tags, it doesn't de-escape.

Comment: What "didn't work"? What result did you expect?

Comment: @deceze The HTML is showing up literally since in the original it's escaped. The wording of this question isn't clear, but in the "example" section you can see the `&gt;` entitized version.

Comment: @tadman I want the OP to clearly state his question, not us interpreting what he probably maybe meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try applying the [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) method to undo the damage that `htmlspecialchars` did when insert it into the database.